# Is it possible to create an optimization model with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mathematical-optimization

**Is it possible to create an optimization model with Ruby on Rails?**

For example, I would like to have the functionality of that Excel has with Solver. I need to create an optimization algorithm/function in my web application and want to know if it is possible to do this with Ruby on Rails. Or is there a gem that can do this?

Comment: It depends on the type of optimization problem you wish to solve: linear programming, non-linear programming, integer or mixed integer programming, one of the network flow problems, dynamic programming problems and so on....

Comment: Hello @CarySwoveland, the optimization problem is linear. I use RiskSolver on excel and it said it was an LP Convex. Do you know if it is possible to create such a model on Ruby on Rails? Or if there is a gem that can help me?

Comment: What you want is a gem that provides a wrapper to a standard LP package, probably written in C. [This](https://github.com/wtaysom/rglpk) and [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/lpsolve/versions/5.5.10.i) are a couple of possibilities.  I have quite a bit of experience with LP models. If you need any help on the modelling side, you can email me at the address given in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you can try Ruby/GSL gem (rb-gsl)

http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/

that gem has Nonlinear Least-Squares Fitting

here is documentation about that.

http://rb-gsl.rubyforge.org/files/rdoc/nonlinearfit_rdoc.html

Comment: Thank you Horacio! I will check out the Ruby/GSL gem.